# Reducing a Collection in Java 8

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream, fold

I am wondering what is the cleanest , perhaps idiomatic, way to something like the following trivial example.

If I have an array (or list, etc) `[1,1,1,2,3,5,5,9]` I want to do a reduction, fold, of sorts, where consecutive numbers are added, leaving only one element.

So `[1,1,1,2,3,5,5,9]` would become `[3,2,3,10,9]`.

---

A slightly more generalized case:

`[object1, object2, object3, object4]` where `object1` and `object2` have some combination of properties that would make it necessary to create a new `object5`  to replace both of them and the result would be `[object5, object3, object4]`.

My actual use case is a bit more complicated, but the idea is similar in iterating over a list, somehow, but not reducing to a single atomic value.

Comment: Not a good candidate for streams, try to solve it using an iterative approach,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reduction is Stream API doesn't work this way. The point of the [reduction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Reduction) (also called as *fold*) is to combine input elements into a single result.

This is clearly not a suitable task for Stream API as long as the computation relies on the consecutive elements based on the equivalence.

You want go for something like this*... which I have no idea to "convert" into Stream API.

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,1,1,2,3,5,5,9);
List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<>();

int i = 0;
while (i < list.size()) {
    int current = list.get(i);
    int next = current;
    int sum = 0;
    int j = i;
    while (current == next) {
        j++;
        sum += next;
        if (j < list.size()) {
            next = list.get(j);
        } else break;
    }
    newList.add(sum);
    i = j;
}

// [3, 2, 3, 10, 9]
System.out.println(newList);
```

*This is clearly not the best solution in terms of performance and readability as long as I really suck in "LeetCode" problems solving. The idea is to demonstrate these solutions don't go well with Stream API.